# Force a window's position or visibility

Tags: windows-7

An app seems to now be invisible.
I have an application pinned on my task bar (Windows 7 + Agent Ransack) that I can no longer see the window of.  When I start it the task bar changes to show it is running, but I can not see the window.  It is as if the window is invisible, permanently minimized or off screen.

10 years of supporting my families PC's and you really can still learn something new everyday.  What can I do to debug?

Answer (score 1):

Most common way (does not work with all windows)

Alt-Tab to this windows search replacement thing

```
Press Alt-Space - Open control menu
M key for Move
Left or right arrow key
```

If you have a german Windows M is V.
If the window is maximized, you first need to put it back to normal size
.. and so on.

Or if you want to mess with every window.. right click on a empty point in taskbar. there are option that you can apply another layout (stack and so on) - this will get ugly and you need to sort manually.